# Добавление элемента в новый вопрос

Tags: javascript, html

Имеется блок с вопросом и ответами. При нажатии на "Добавить вопрос", а затем в новом вопросе "Добавить ответ" - добавляет новый ответ только в первый вопрос.
Как сделать, чтобы добавлялся новый ответ в тот вопрос, в котором была нажата кнопка "Добавить ответ"?

Отображение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
var wrapper = document.getElementsByClassName("wrapper")[0];
var answerWrapper = document.getElementsByClassName("answer-wrapper")[0];
var wrapperTemplate =
  `<section class="quiz"><div class="question"><h2>Question</h2><input type="text"></div><div class="answer-wrapper"><h2>Answer</h2><div class="answer-item"><input type="text"><input type="checkbox"></div><div class="answer-item"><input type="text"><input type="checkbox"></div></div><button onclick="addA(this)">Add Answer</button></section>`;
var answerTemplate =
  `<div class="answer-item"><input type="text"><input type="checkbox"></div>`;

function addQ() {
  wrapper.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", wrapperTemplate);
}

function addA(elem) {
  answerWrapper.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", answerTemplate);
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

h2 {
  color: gray;
  font-family: monospace;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 1rem;
}

.quiz {
  padding: 0.5rem;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}

aside {
  margin: 1rem;
}

input[type="text"] {
  margin: 0.2rem 0;
  outline: none;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  margin: 0.3rem 0.2rem;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="quiz">
      <div class="question">
        <h2>Question</h2>
        <input type="text">
      </div>
      <div class="answer-wrapper">
        <h2>Answer</h2>
        <div class="answer-item">
          <input type="text"><input type="checkbox">
        </div>
        <div class="answer-item">
          <input type="text"><input type="checkbox">
        </div>
      </div>
      <button onclick="addA(this)">Add Answer</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <aside>
    <button onclick="addQ()">Add Question</button>
  </aside>
</main>
```

Comment: Вы же в `addA` добавляете шаблон `answerWrapper` к `answerWrapper`, который ссылается на первый вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var wrapper = document.getElementsByClassName("wrapper")[0];
var answerWrapper = document.getElementsByClassName("answer-wrapper")[0];
var wrapperTemplate =
  `<section class="quiz"><div class="question"><h2>Question</h2><input type="text"></div><div class="answer-wrapper"><h2>Answer</h2><div class="answer-item"><input type="text"><input type="checkbox"></div><div class="answer-item"><input type="text"><input type="checkbox"></div></div><button onclick="addA(this)">Add Answer</button></section>`;
var answerTemplate =
  `<div class="answer-item"><input type="text"><input type="checkbox"></div>`;

function addQ() {
  wrapper.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", wrapperTemplate);
}

function addA(elem) {
  elem.parentNode.querySelector('.answer-wrapper').insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", answerTemplate);
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

h2 {
  color: gray;
  font-family: monospace;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 1rem;
}

.quiz {
  padding: 0.5rem;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}

aside {
  margin: 1rem;
}

input[type="text"] {
  margin: 0.2rem 0;
  outline: none;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  margin: 0.3rem 0.2rem;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="quiz">
      <div class="question">
        <h2>Question</h2>
        <input type="text">
      </div>
      <div class="answer-wrapper">
        <h2>Answer</h2>
        <div class="answer-item">
          <input type="text"><input type="checkbox">
        </div>
        <div class="answer-item">
          <input type="text"><input type="checkbox">
        </div>
      </div>
      <button onclick="addA(this)">Add Answer</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <aside>
    <button onclick="addQ()">Add Question</button>
  </aside>
</main>
```

Comment: Если что исправил `answer-item` на `answer-wrapper`. В него нужно было добавлять. Спасибо за помощь, что бы я без тебя делал))

Comment: Без броблем! :)

Comment: @Arthur, Не забудьте принять ответ, если решено.

Comment: дубль 2: Без броблем!:) Жду, когда 10 минут пройдёт))